# What is this serialization format called?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jms, amazon-sqs

I am having trouble finding the name of this format and hence figuring out how to convert it to a POJO

```
{
    ExampleKey1: ExampleValue1,
    ExampleKey2: ExampleValue2,
    ExampleObjectKey: {
        "ObjectKey" : "ObjectValue"
    }
}
```

This is clearly not a JSON or an ION. Any suggestions?

A little bit of background:

I am trying to read SQS messages (published via SNS) asynchronously using JMS like so: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/getting-started.html - go to the section "Receiving Messages Asynchronously"

The message i receive is like so:

```
{MessageId: 123-123-123,ReceiptHandle: BigTextWithCharactersLike+and/andNumbers123,MD5OfBody: AlphaNumberic123,Body: {
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "uuid-uuid-uuid-uuid",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:someARN",
  "Message" : "{\"this\":\"is\",\"the\":\"part\",\"i\":\"am\",\"interested\":\"in\"}",
  "Timestamp" : "timestamp",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : "alphanumeric+charatersLike+and/and==",
  "SigningCertURL" : "https://an-sns-url",
  "UnsubscribeURL" : "https://an-sns-url"
},Attributes: {},MessageAttributes: {}}
```

This i've found by doing the following onMessage:

```
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        // Cast the received message as TextMessage and print the text to screen.
        System.out.println("Received: " + ((TextMessage) message).getText());
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I've replaced actual values with dummy ones above. If I can parse the above into a POJO, I will be able to extract the "Body" and hence the "Message" which is the part i am interested in.

PS: notice that the text is basically the POJO https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/model/Message.html

Comment: Why is it not JSON? Because the keys aren't quoted?

Comment: That looks like https://hjson.org/

Comment: @shmosel it is not valid JSON because the keys are not in quotes. I am not sure what then OP intended with ExampleValue2. Perhaps they will elaborate.

Comment: @bhspencer The fact that the keys aren't in quotes is not a big deal. JS allows it and libraries like Jackson have an option to deserialize keys without quotes. But I overlooked the unquoted values. That could be more of a problem.

Comment: @bhspencer what do you mean by OP intended with ExampleValue2? Unquoted values are a big problem.

Comment: From your example I could not tell if ExampleValue2 is supposed to be a String or some more generic place holder. Either way you can parse the above example with a java hjson parser. https://github.com/hjson/hjson-java

Comment: Any other information? File extension? Class name that produces or consumes it?

Comment: @RobinGreen i am trying to use jms to consume SQS messages. The message is pushed to SQS via SNS. Here is how i am reading it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/getting-started.html - go to section "Receiving Messages Asynchronously"

Comment: Edited the question adding more details into where the message is coming from

Comment: I don't believe you are faithfully reproducing whatever it is that you are actually trying to describe, @akshitBhatia.  An SNS message is a string.  A message that goes from SNS to SQS is a string inside a JSON object inside a JSON object, and neither of those services cares what is in that string, as long as it is a character string and not a blob.  You just have to JSON-deserialize through multiple iterations to get the original string, which is whatever you originally put onto the topic.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the SNS message string which i want to get to is   "Message" : "{\"this\":\"is\",\"the\":\"part\",\"i\":\"am\",\"interested\":\"in\"}" - and to get this out, i will have to JSON-deserialize it. If you notice the rest of the SNS message - it is a valid JSON which i can again deserialize. However the structure outside it which is similar to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/model/Message.html is not a valid JSON - which is what my question is. I believe in that i have "faithfully" reproduced the issue and asked the right question.

Comment: Ohhhh.  I see what you are seeing, @akshitBhatia. I thought you were referring the inner... not the outer.  That's an artifact of your cast, a "helpful" human-readable stringification.  It isn't what the actual message looks like.  You should be able to `message.getBody()`, and *that* should be valid JSON that you can deserialize.  `Message` from inside there, should then be valid JSON, which is the original message.